# How to implement a semaphore class using the filesystem

Tags: c#, semaphore

I am a huge fan of c# semaphore class, but I need to extend it to use files instead. The semaphore class will be implemented across many applications and need to be synchronized. These applications will control access to the windows clipboard and access to edit other files. In some cases multiple threads or processes can enter a semaphore at once.

Comment: why file now? you need an application that just act as semaphore(agent), then other apps contact by socket with it, I'm wondering how do you really want to have semaphore with file!?

Comment: I dont need a semaphore application(agent). I need a file based semaphore class and this semaphore class will be integrated in other applications.

Comment: as I said, it's not good idea control or communicate with files, use socket instead

Comment: Ah I see. I will need to do I little studying on network programming. Let me research to see how much effort this will take.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered using named system semaphore? Named semaphore is controlled by the system, and can be used by many processes running on the same system. One process creates the semaphore and other just open it's instance. Windows is ensuring that the semapahore state is correct.

Example usage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wz356skf.aspx